# Partial proof explanation: Every bounded sequence in $R^k$ contains a convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, real-numbers

I am trying to understand the notation and implication of this part of a proof from Theorem 3.6 of Principles of Mathematical Analysis by W. Rudin:

**Theorem:**
Every bounded sequence in $R^k$ contains a convergent subsequence

**Proof (partial):**
Let $E$ be the range of $\{p_n\}$. If $E$ is finite then there is a $p \in E$ and a 
sequence $\{n_i\}$ with $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < ...$, such that 
$p_{n_1} = p_{n_2} = ... = p$. 
The subsequence $\{p_{n_i}\}$ so obtained converges evidently to $p$.

I'm having trouble understanding what this part of the proof is trying to say (but I'm pretty sure it's very simple).

Comment: It's covering the case that $E$ is finite. In that case, there is a point $p$ which occurs for infinitely many $n$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E$ is finite, then the sequence $\{p_n\}$ is placing infinitely many things into finitely many bins.  Suppose the range $E$ of the sequence $\{p_n\}$ is $E=\{p,q,r\}$.  Since $\{p_n\}$ is infinite, at least one of $p,q,$ and $r$ (say $p$) must be hit infinitely many times by the sequence.  Then we can take a subsequence $p_{n_1},p_{n_2},\ldots$ which is just $p,p,\ldots$.  Certainly this subsequence converges to $p$.

Comment: Wow.. I knew I was being dumb. Thanks for the clarification! I found the notation kind of weird, but now that you've explained in simplified terms, I can see what it's saying.